# How to SELECT specific records having the criteria record id + 1

Tags: php, mysql

Currently creating a search page in php for existing system. The data comes from a table with unusual structure of handling of data.

A sample snapshot of existing system, Sales History Webpage

[image]

I observed that if we are going to look the table it is using, the data we saw on Sales History Webpage earlier comes from 1 pair of rows.

[image]

As we can see, if we are going to search for
`player_id` 956 (gang) using SQL query, we would get `player_point_id` 96834 not 96835.
From the existing system, what the Sales History Webpage shows is `player_point_id` 96835 record but it also shows the recipient `player_id` 956 (gang). It seems that a pair of record goes like a recipient is found at `player_point_id` 96834 and the sender is found at `player_point_id` 96835

Let's say for example the search criteria is `player_id` 956 only, let' say it found 100 records. It poses a problem that I need to look for the Next records of the `player_point_id`s it get.

So far I'm trying to do it on php with arrays but it seems a waste I'm running out of ideas. Is this possible to be solved in SQL using an SQL query? If not, other PHP ideas are welcome.

Comment: I'm afraid this is very unclear. Consider editing your question to make clear the precise logic of your data model, and what is required.

Comment: Hi I updated the question. Let me know if its clear or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work I think. This gets both the rows with player_id 956 and the row(s) with player_point_id one greater than those. You can drop the last line of code if you only want to retrieve the second rows (wasn't really clear from your question what you actually wanted to find).

```
SELECT t.column, 
       t.another_column 
FROM   table_name t 
WHERE  t.player_point_id IN (SELECT ( player_point_id + 1 ) 
                             FROM   table_name 
                             WHERE  player_id = '956') 
        OR player_id = '956';
```

Comment: I reviewed and adjusted your query to the search criteria i think what fits in this kind of situation. It turns out your query is the best and the closest I found. Thank you very much for this

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
//get current point id

$sql = "select player_point_id from table_name where player_id=$id";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$player_details = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$ppid = $player_details['player_point_id'];

$ppid += 1;
//get details from the next point id

$sql = "select operator_id,  kiyosuku_id from table_name where player_point_id=$ppid";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$point_details = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$operator_id = $point_details['operator_id']; //required answer
$kiyosuku_id = $point_details['kiyosuku_id']; //required answer
```

The code is a little inefficient but would surely work.

Comment: Hi I apologize if the question turn out hard to understand. I updated the question. Let me know if its clear or not